# 'variable': initialized auto or register variable not allowed at function scope in 'naked' function

Tags: c++

```
int __declspec(naked) Testing(int _byte, int _byte_size) {

    int byte_size = _byte_size;
    BYTE* bytec = new BYTE[byte_size];
    memcpy(reinterpret_cast<void*>(bytec),
           reinterpret_cast<void*>(_byte), byte_size);

    int RE_format = 0;
 }
```

This is whats cause the error, How would I go about fixing this? I have other code that I don't want to disclose but these are the main variables that are causing the error C2489.

Comment: That code doesn't make much sens. Useless variables, dubious casts, no return.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the error message is pretty self-explanatory, and the following at least compiles, although I'm not sure what use it is:

```
int __declspec(naked) Testing(int _byte, int _byte_size) {

    int byte_size;
    byte_size = _byte_size;
    BYTE* bytec;
    bytec = new BYTE[byte_size];
    memcpy(reinterpret_cast<void*>(bytec),
           reinterpret_cast<void*>(_byte), byte_size);

    int RE_format;
    RE_format = 0;
 }
```

[Live demo](https://godbolt.org/z/Zcng_g)